# What does “kind enough to die” phrase mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does "kind enough to die" phrase mean? Rocket told this to Thor in avengers endgame, not to save her mother(when they came to the past), and to prioritize their task to save the half of the universe who are kind enough to die. if I can remember.

Does this mean that these people don't deserve to die? or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a figurative use of the idiom [**be kind enough**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20kind%20enough):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   *formal*
>   —used to make a request
>   // Would you *be kind enough* to show me the way?

In *Endgame*, it's a kind of sarcastic reference to the past happening in a way that wasn't factual:

- Thanos: "Hey, I'm looking for some volunteers. I need about half of you to die when I snap my fingers. Which of you would be *kind enough* to do that for me?"
- *(many people raise their hands)*
- Thanos: "Thank you very much!"
- Rocket (years later): "Those people were *kind enough* to die."

In reality, permission wasn't asked, nor was it given. It had nothing to do with politeness or anybody deserving to die. That's why it's a sarcastic reference to the event and the dead.